# C text formatter characters count is off

Tags: c, string, loops, whitespace

So I have an assignment to format text according to rules and eventually print out the number of characters in the string (including `\n` and spaces, anything but the `\0` at the end of the string).

Basically, a valid input is ended with a dot but I think I have a few more whitespaces after the final dots.
I have tried several approaches such as loop that replaces spaces with `\0` starting from the end of the string.
nothing seems to work though...

**EDIT** The requirements are:

1. to convert double-dots(..) to a new line
2. delete multiple spaces leaving only one,
3. making sure that there isn't a space prior to a comma or a dot
4. making sure that there is single space after a comma or dot.
5. not changing the original content between apostrophes.
6. and validating that there are Capital letters only in the correct places (new line\paragraph).

we are required to do all of the code in the main function (unfortunately) and me code usually mistake the characters count by 1-2 extra in the count (probably do to extra spaces after the last dot

this is an example of input that my code fails at counting characters

```
the LANGUAGE  "C" is a procedural              programming language     .It was initially developed by "Dennis Ritchie"..            the Main feAtures of "C" language include low-level access to memory, simple set of keywords, and clean style                .
```

```
int main() {
    char ans;

    printf("*************** Welcome to the text cleaner ***************\n\n");

    do
    {
        int length, i, j = 0;
        int word, sentence, para, space;
        char tin[601], tout[601], * dex, * pos;
        printf("\nPlease enter text:\n");
        gets_s(tin, 600);
        length = strlen(tin);

        dex = strchr(tin, '.'); //converts double dots to new line
        while (dex != NULL)
        {
            if (tin[dex - tin + 1] == '.') {
                tin[dex - tin + 1] = '\n';
            }
            dex = strchr(dex + 1, '.');
        }
        length = strlen(tin);


        dex = strchr(tin, ' '); //converting multiple spaces to single space
        while (dex != NULL)
        {
            while (dex != NULL && tin[dex - tin + 1] == ' ')
            {
                for (i = dex - tin + 1; i < strlen(tin); i++)
                {
                    tin[i - 1] = tin[i];
                }
                dex = strchr(dex, ' ');
                j++;
            }
            dex = strchr(dex + 1, ' ');
        }

        tin[length - j] = '\0';
        j = 0;

        dex = strchr(tin, '\n');

        while (dex != NULL && tin[dex-tin+1] == ' ') //delets spaces in the beggining of new row
        {
            for (i = dex - tin + 1;i < strlen(tin);i++) {
                tin[i] = tin[i + 1];
            }
            dex = strchr(dex + 1, '\n');
        }

        dex = strchr(tin, ','); //deletes space before comma
        while (dex != NULL && tin[dex - tin - 1] == ' ')
        {
            for (i = dex - tin - 1; i < strlen(tin); i++)
            {
                tin[i] = tin[i+1];
            }
            dex = strchr(dex+1, ',');
        }

        dex = strchr(tin, '.'); //deletes space before dots
        while (dex != NULL && tin[dex - tin - 1] == ' ')
        {
            for (i = dex - tin - 1; i < strlen(tin); i++)
            {
                tin[i] = tin[i+1];
            }
            dex = strchr(dex + 1, '.');
        }



        dex = strchr(tin, ','); // adds space after comma
        while (dex != NULL && tin[dex - tin + 1] != ' ')    
        {
            if (tin[dex - tin + 1] != '\n')
            {
                tin[strlen(tin) + 1] = '\0';
                for (i = strlen(tin); i > dex - tin; i--)
                {
                    if (i == dex - tin + 1)
                    {
                        tin[i] = ' ';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tin[i] = tin[i - 1];
                    }
                }
                dex = strchr(dex + 1, ',');
            }
        }

        dex = strchr(tin, '.'); // adds space after dot

        while (dex != NULL && tin[dex - tin + 1] != ' ')
        {
                tin[strlen(tin) + 1] = '\0';
                if (tin[dex - tin + 1] == '\n')
                {
                    dex = strchr(dex + 1, '.');
                }
                else
                {
                    for (i = strlen(tin); i > dex - tin; i--)
                    {
                        if (i == dex - tin + 1)
                        {
                            tin[i] = ' ';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tin[i] = tin[i - 1];
                        }
                    }
                    dex = strchr(dex + 1, '.');
                }           
        }

        strcpy_s(tout, sizeof(tout), tin);
        _strlwr_s(tout,sizeof(tout)); //copies and lowercasing the input string

        dex = strchr(tin, '"');
        
        if (dex != NULL) {
            pos = strchr(dex + 1, '"');

            while (dex != NULL)
            {
                for (i = dex - tin; i < pos - tin; i++) {
                    tout[i] = tin[i];
                }
                dex = strchr(pos + 1, '"');
                if (dex)
                {
                    pos = strchr(dex + 1, '"');
                }
            }  //making sure that the letters in the quotes have't been lowercased
        }
        
        _strupr_s(tin, sizeof(tin));

        dex = strchr(tout, '.');
        pos = strchr(tin, '.');
        while (dex != NULL && pos != NULL)
        {
                tout[dex - tout + 2] = tin[pos - tin + 2];
                dex = strchr(dex + 1, '.');     
                pos = strchr(pos + 1, '.');
        }   
        //CAPSLOCK

        dex = strchr(tout, '.'); //deletes space before dots
        while (dex != NULL)
        {
            if (tout[dex - tout - 1] == ' ')
            {
                for (i = dex - tout - 1; i < strlen(tout); i++)
                {
                    tout[i] = tout[i+1];
                }
            }
            
            dex = strchr(dex + 1, '.');
        }

        if (tout[0] == ' ') {
            for (i = 0 ;i < strlen(tout); i++) {
                tout[i] = tout[i + 1];
            }
        }//handeling single space in the beggining of the string

        if (tout[0] >= 'a' && tout[0] <= 'z') {
            tout[0] -= 32;
        } //First letter always capital


        word = 0;
        sentence = 0;
        para = 1;
        space = 0;
        length = strlen(tout);

        for (i = 0; tout[i] != '\0';i++)
        {
            if (tout[i] == ' ' && tout[i + 1] != ' ')
                word++;
        }



        dex = strchr(tout, '.');
        while (dex != NULL)
        {
            sentence++;
            dex = strchr(dex + 1, '.');
        }

        dex = strchr(tout, '\n');
        while (dex != NULL)
        {
            space++;
            para++;
            word++;
            dex = strchr(dex + 1, '\n');
        } 

        //dex = strchr(tout, '-');
        //while (dex != NULL)
        //{
        //  word++;
        //  dex = strchr(dex + 1, '-');
        //}

        printf_s("\nText after cleaning:\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf_s("%s\n\n", tout);
        printf_s("characters: %d | words: %d | sentences: %d | paragraphs: %d\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n",length, word, sentence, para);
        printf_s("\nIf you want to clean another string press (y): ");
        scanf_s(" %c", &ans, 1);
        if (ans == 'y')
        {
            gets_s(tin, 600);

        }
    } while (ans =='y');
```

Comment: Please define "fails"

Comment: To get the number of characters just use `strlen(tin)`

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and list the exact requirements you have. In your code comments, you have several: `double dots to new line`, `multiple spaces to single space`, `delets spaces in the beggining of new row`, `deletes space before comma`, `...` But, your code is overly complex for what it needs to do.

Comment: This code badly needs modularisation (breaking into sub-functions) as there are clearly logic duplications that just need parameterisation, and are also re-implementing standard library functions.  With that said, there are a number of 'rules' to be implemented, and it might well be better approached with a state machine (although that might be beyond the skill level of the OP and one has to start somewhere)

Comment: First of all thank you all,
@Jabberwocky I've edited and defined fails (counts 1-2 more than there is).

Comment: @Barmar this is the way but there is something broken and probably hidden characters after the last dot.

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you, I've edited and added the requirements.

Comment: @DaveMeehan I know and agree with you, I have past experience in front end and python, unfortunately, this is a beginners course (part of my bachelor's) and they make us do it all in the main...

Comment: Does `gets_s` do anything differently than `fgets`?  It seems absurd to use non-standard functions for an assignment like this.

Comment: `not changing the original content between apostrophes.` Do you mean _quotes_? And, do you want to preserve multiple spaces inside them or not?

Comment: Can you use _two_ buffers or _must_ you do this "in place"?

Comment: And, do you want to keep `..` as is inside quotes (e.g.) `"hello..world"` is unchanged?

Comment: @NitaiDan What kind of hell is this?  What do they think they are teaching you here?

Comment: @DaveMeehan With state variables I think this can be done in a single loop in one pass. That may be the rationale.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes, I'd got stuck in thinking that they were being asked to do all that repetition, despite already suggesting a simplification.  I've posted possible a solution.

Comment: This could definitely use a [lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72180149/2472827) to make your code much shorter. `gets_s` is in the `C11` standard as an "optional" function (_ie_ Microsoft.) Point 4 expands the buffer, so it can't be in-place unless we just report an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the top comments, this can be done in a single loop with state variables.

A few assumptions:

1. Whenever we see `..` (which is converted to a newline), it starts a new paragraph
2. What you called "apostrophe", I'm calling a double quote (as that's the only thing that made sense).
3. Within quotes *nothing* is converted
4. Quotes [themselves] are copied over (i.e. *not* stripped)

---

Unfortunately, I had to completely refactor the code. It is annotated. I realize you have to *only* use `main`. The extra functions are merely for debug, so they "don't count":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int opt_d;                          // debug
int opt_quo;                        // preserve quote

#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_d) \
            printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)         do { } while (0)
#endif

#define COPYX(_chr) \
    do { \
        *dst++ = _chr; \
        dbgprt("COPY %2.2X/%s\n",_chr,showchr(_chr)); \
    } while (0)

#define COPY \
    COPYX(chr)

#define WHITEOUT \
    do { \
        if (! white) \
            break; \
        COPYX(' '); \
        white = 0; \
        ctr_word += 1; \
    } while (0)

const char *
showchr(int chr)
{
    static char buf[10];

    if ((chr >= 0x20) && (chr <= 0x7E))
        sprintf(buf,"%c",chr);
    else
        sprintf(buf,"{%2.2X}",chr);

    return buf;
}

void
showbuf(const char *buf,const char *who)
{
    const char *sep = "'";

    printf("%s: %s",who,sep);

    for (int chr = *buf++;  chr != 0;  chr = *buf++)
        printf("%s",showchr(chr));

    printf("%s\n",sep);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char inp[1000];
    char buf[1000];
    char *src;
    char *dst;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_d = ! opt_d;
            break;
        case 'q':
            opt_quo = ! opt_quo;
            break;
        }
    }

    opt_quo = ! opt_quo;

    const char *file;
    if (argc > 0)
        file = *argv;
    else
        file = "inp.txt";

    FILE *xfsrc = fopen(file,"r");
    if (xfsrc == NULL) {
        perror(file);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(inp,sizeof(inp),xfsrc) != NULL) {
        strcpy(buf,inp);

        src = buf;
        dst = buf;

        int quo = 0;
        int white = 0;
        int dot = 1;
        int ctr_sent = 0;
        int ctr_word = 0;
        int ctr_para = 1;

        for (int chr = *src++;  chr != 0;  chr = *src++) {
            dbgprt("LOOP %2.2X/%s quo=%d white=%d dot=%d word=%d sent=%d para=%d\n",
                chr,showchr(chr),quo,white,dot,
                ctr_word,ctr_sent,ctr_para);

            // got a quote
            if (chr == '"') {
                if (! quo)
                    WHITEOUT;
                if (opt_quo)
                    COPY;
                quo = ! quo;
                continue;
            }

            // non-quote
            else {
                if (quo) {
                    COPY;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // got a dot
            if (chr == '.') {
                dot = 1;

                // double dot --> newline (new paragraph)
                if (*src == '.') {
                    COPYX('\n');
                    ++src;
                    ctr_para += 1;
                    continue;
                }

                COPY;

                white = 1;
                continue;
            }

            // from fgets, this can _only_ occur at the end of the buffer
            if (chr == '\n') {
                dot = 1;
                white = 1;
                COPY;
                break;
            }

            // accumulate/skip over whitespace
            if (chr == ' ') {
                white = 1;
                continue;
            }

            // output accumulated whitespace
            WHITEOUT;

            // got uppercase -- convert to lowercase if we're not at the start
            // of a sentence
            if (isupper(chr)) {
                if (! dot)
                    chr = tolower(chr);
            }

            // got lowercase -- capitalize if we're just starting a sentence
            else {
                if (islower(chr)) {
                    if (dot)
                        chr = toupper(chr);
                }
            }

            COPY;

            // count sentences
            if (dot)
                ctr_sent += 1;

            dot = 0;
        }

        *dst = 0;

        showbuf(inp,"inp");
        showbuf(buf,"buf");

#if 0
        if (dot)
            ctr_word += 1;
#endif

        printf("TOTAL: length=%zu sentences=%d paragraphs=%d words=%d\n",
            strlen(buf),ctr_sent,ctr_para,ctr_word);
    }

    fclose(xfsrc);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
inp: 'the LANGUAGE  "C" is a procedural              programming language     .It was initially developed by "Dennis Ritchie"..            the Main feAtures of "C" language include low-level access to memory, simple set of keywords, and clean style                .{0A}'
buf: 'The language "C" is a procedural programming language. It was initially developed by "Dennis Ritchie"{0A} The main features of "C" language include low-level access to memory, simple set of keywords, and clean style.{0A}'
TOTAL: length=214 sentences=3 paragraphs=2 words=31
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Great, thank you! I've taken what you've done and implemented it on my code, basically, the professor restricted us to us only stdio.h and string.h libraries so I couldn't use any other functions... –
> Nitai Dan

You're welcome!

I'm glad you were able to incorporate my code into yours. That's the best of all possible scenarios for learning.

I wasn't sure I had added enough annotation to make my algorithm clear, so I had cleaned it up a bit and was debating whether to post it or not. It is posted below.

Based on what you just said, I'm [still] not sure whether *creating* your own functions would have been allowed. As I said, *debug* functions would [probably] be okay if they don't change the algorithm.

Anyway, here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int opt_d;                          // debug
int opt_quo;                        // preserve quote
int opt_x;                          // show space as hex

#define _dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)

#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_d) \
            _dbgprt(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)         do { } while (0)
#endif

#if DEBUG
#define COPYX(_chr) \
    do { \
        *dst++ = _chr; \
        copy = 1; \
        if (_chr != src[-1]) \
            _dbgprt(" COPY %s\n",_showchr(_chr,1)); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define COPYX(_chr) \
    do { \
        *dst++ = _chr; \
    } while (0)
#endif

#define COPY \
    COPYX(chr)

// output accumulated white space and increment count of number of words
#define SPACEOUT \
    do { \
        if (! spc) \
            break; \
        spc = 0; \
        COPYX(' '); \
        ctr_word += 1; \
    } while (0)

const char *
_showchr(int chr,int xflg)
{
    static char buf[10];
    int lo = xflg ? 0x21 : 0x20;

    if ((chr >= lo) && (chr <= 0x7E))
        sprintf(buf,"%c",chr);
    else
        sprintf(buf,"{%2.2X}",chr);

    return buf;
}

const char *
showchr(int chr)
{

    return _showchr(chr,opt_x);
}

void
showbuf(const char *buf,const char *who)
{
    const char *sep = "'";

    printf("%s: %s",who,sep);

    for (int chr = *buf++;  chr != 0;  chr = *buf++)
        printf("%s",showchr(chr));

    printf("%s\n",sep);
}

void
dbgint(const char *sym,int val)
{
    do {
        int ctr = isupper(sym[0]);

        if (! ctr) {
            if (! val)
                break;
        }

        _dbgprt(" %s",sym);

        if (ctr)
            _dbgprt("%d",val);
    } while (0);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char inp[1000];
    char buf[1000];
    char *src;
    char *dst;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_d = ! opt_d;
            break;
        case 'q':
            opt_quo = ! opt_quo;
            break;
        case 'x':
            opt_x = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    opt_quo = ! opt_quo;

    const char *file;
    if (argc > 0)
        file = *argv;
    else
        file = "inp.txt";

    FILE *xfsrc = fopen(file,"r");
    if (xfsrc == NULL) {
        perror(file);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(inp,sizeof(inp),xfsrc) != NULL) {
        strcpy(buf,inp);

        src = buf;
        dst = buf;

        // state variables
        int quo = 0;  // 1=within quoted string
        int spc = 0;  // 1=space seen
        int dot = 1;  // 1=period/newline seen

        // counters
        int ctr_sent = 0;  // number of sentences
        int ctr_word = 0;  // number of words
        int ctr_para = 1;  // number of paragraphs

#if DEBUG
        int copy = 0;
        int ochr = 0;
#endif

        for (int chr = *src++;  chr != 0;  chr = *src++) {
#if DEBUG
            if (opt_d) {
                // show if we skipped the prior char (and it was _not_ a space)
                if ((! copy) && (ochr != ' '))
                    _dbgprt("SKIP\n");
                copy = 0;
                ochr = chr;

                _dbgprt("LOOP %s",showchr(chr));
                dbgint("W:",ctr_word);
                dbgint("S:",ctr_sent);
                dbgint("P:",ctr_para);
                dbgint("quo",quo);
                dbgint("spc",spc);
                dbgint("dot",dot);
                _dbgprt("\n");
            }
#endif

            // got a quote
            if (chr == '"') {
                // flush whitespace if starting a quoted string
                if (! quo)
                    SPACEOUT;

                // copy the quote
                if (opt_quo)
                    COPY;

                // flip the quote mode
                quo = ! quo;
                continue;
            }

            // non-quote
            else {
                // if inside a quoted string, just copy out the char verbatim
                if (quo) {
                    COPY;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // got a dot
            if (chr == '.') {
                dot = 1;

                // double dot --> newline (new paragraph)
                if (*src == '.') {
                    COPYX('\n');
                    ++src;
                    ctr_para += 1;
                    continue;
                }

                COPY;

                // force whitespace mode (ensure space after dot)
                // (e.g.) change:
                //   i go.he goes.
                // into:
                //   i go. he goes.
                spc = 1;
                continue;
            }

            // from fgets, this can _only_ occur at the end of the buffer
            if (chr == '\n') {
                dot = 1;
                spc = 1;
                COPY;
                break;
            }

            // accumulate/skip over whitespace
            if (chr == ' ') {
                spc = 1;
                continue;
            }

            // output accumulated whitespace
            SPACEOUT;

            // convert case
            if (dot)
                chr = toupper(chr);
            else
                chr = tolower(chr);

            // output the current character -- it's _not_ special
            COPY;

            // count sentences
            if (dot)
                ctr_sent += 1;

            // we're no longer at the start of a sentence
            dot = 0;
        }

        *dst = 0;

        if (opt_x == 1)
            opt_x = 0;
        showbuf(inp,"inp");
        showbuf(buf,"buf");

#if 0
        if (dot)
            ctr_word += 1;
#endif

        printf("TOTAL: length=%zu sentences=%d paragraphs=%d words=%d\n",
            strlen(buf),ctr_sent,ctr_para,ctr_word);
    }

    fclose(xfsrc);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Output with `-d`:

```
SKIP
LOOP t W:0 S:0 P:1 dot
LOOP h W:0 S:1 P:1
LOOP e W:0 S:1 P:1
LOOP   W:0 S:1 P:1
LOOP L W:0 S:1 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP A W:1 S:1 P:1
LOOP N W:1 S:1 P:1
LOOP G W:1 S:1 P:1
LOOP U W:1 S:1 P:1
LOOP A W:1 S:1 P:1
LOOP G W:1 S:1 P:1
LOOP E W:1 S:1 P:1
LOOP   W:1 S:1 P:1
LOOP   W:1 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP " W:1 S:1 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP C W:2 S:1 P:1 quo
LOOP " W:2 S:1 P:1 quo
LOOP   W:2 S:1 P:1
LOOP i W:2 S:1 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP s W:3 S:1 P:1
LOOP   W:3 S:1 P:1
LOOP a W:3 S:1 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP   W:4 S:1 P:1
LOOP p W:4 S:1 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP r W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP o W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP c W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP e W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP d W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP u W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP r W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP a W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP l W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP p W:5 S:1 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP r W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP o W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP g W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP r W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP a W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP m W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP m W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP i W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP n W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP g W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP   W:6 S:1 P:1
LOOP l W:6 S:1 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP a W:7 S:1 P:1
LOOP n W:7 S:1 P:1
LOOP g W:7 S:1 P:1
LOOP u W:7 S:1 P:1
LOOP a W:7 S:1 P:1
LOOP g W:7 S:1 P:1
LOOP e W:7 S:1 P:1
LOOP   W:7 S:1 P:1
LOOP   W:7 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:7 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:7 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP   W:7 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP . W:7 S:1 P:1 spc
LOOP I W:7 S:1 P:1 spc dot
 COPY {20}
LOOP t W:8 S:2 P:1
LOOP   W:8 S:2 P:1
LOOP w W:8 S:2 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP a W:9 S:2 P:1
LOOP s W:9 S:2 P:1
LOOP   W:9 S:2 P:1
LOOP i W:9 S:2 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP n W:10 S:2 P:1
LOOP i W:10 S:2 P:1
LOOP t W:10 S:2 P:1
LOOP i W:10 S:2 P:1
LOOP a W:10 S:2 P:1
LOOP l W:10 S:2 P:1
LOOP l W:10 S:2 P:1
LOOP y W:10 S:2 P:1
LOOP   W:10 S:2 P:1
LOOP d W:10 S:2 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP e W:11 S:2 P:1
LOOP v W:11 S:2 P:1
LOOP e W:11 S:2 P:1
LOOP l W:11 S:2 P:1
LOOP o W:11 S:2 P:1
LOOP p W:11 S:2 P:1
LOOP e W:11 S:2 P:1
LOOP d W:11 S:2 P:1
LOOP   W:11 S:2 P:1
LOOP b W:11 S:2 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP y W:12 S:2 P:1
LOOP   W:12 S:2 P:1
LOOP " W:12 S:2 P:1 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP D W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP e W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP n W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP n W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP i W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP s W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP R W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP i W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP t W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP c W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP h W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP i W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP e W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP " W:13 S:2 P:1 quo
LOOP . W:13 S:2 P:1
 COPY {0A}
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP   W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
LOOP t W:13 S:2 P:2 spc dot
 COPY {20}
 COPY T
LOOP h W:14 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:14 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:14 S:3 P:2
LOOP M W:14 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
 COPY m
LOOP a W:15 S:3 P:2
LOOP i W:15 S:3 P:2
LOOP n W:15 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:15 S:3 P:2
LOOP f W:15 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP e W:16 S:3 P:2
LOOP A W:16 S:3 P:2
 COPY a
LOOP t W:16 S:3 P:2
LOOP u W:16 S:3 P:2
LOOP r W:16 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:16 S:3 P:2
LOOP s W:16 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:16 S:3 P:2
LOOP o W:16 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP f W:17 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:17 S:3 P:2
LOOP " W:17 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP C W:18 S:3 P:2 quo
LOOP " W:18 S:3 P:2 quo
LOOP   W:18 S:3 P:2
LOOP l W:18 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP a W:19 S:3 P:2
LOOP n W:19 S:3 P:2
LOOP g W:19 S:3 P:2
LOOP u W:19 S:3 P:2
LOOP a W:19 S:3 P:2
LOOP g W:19 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:19 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:19 S:3 P:2
LOOP i W:19 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP n W:20 S:3 P:2
LOOP c W:20 S:3 P:2
LOOP l W:20 S:3 P:2
LOOP u W:20 S:3 P:2
LOOP d W:20 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:20 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:20 S:3 P:2
LOOP l W:20 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP o W:21 S:3 P:2
LOOP w W:21 S:3 P:2
LOOP - W:21 S:3 P:2
LOOP l W:21 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:21 S:3 P:2
LOOP v W:21 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:21 S:3 P:2
LOOP l W:21 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:21 S:3 P:2
LOOP a W:21 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP c W:22 S:3 P:2
LOOP c W:22 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:22 S:3 P:2
LOOP s W:22 S:3 P:2
LOOP s W:22 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:22 S:3 P:2
LOOP t W:22 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP o W:23 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:23 S:3 P:2
LOOP m W:23 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP e W:24 S:3 P:2
LOOP m W:24 S:3 P:2
LOOP o W:24 S:3 P:2
LOOP r W:24 S:3 P:2
LOOP y W:24 S:3 P:2
LOOP , W:24 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:24 S:3 P:2
LOOP s W:24 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP i W:25 S:3 P:2
LOOP m W:25 S:3 P:2
LOOP p W:25 S:3 P:2
LOOP l W:25 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:25 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:25 S:3 P:2
LOOP s W:25 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP e W:26 S:3 P:2
LOOP t W:26 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:26 S:3 P:2
LOOP o W:26 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP f W:27 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:27 S:3 P:2
LOOP k W:27 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP e W:28 S:3 P:2
LOOP y W:28 S:3 P:2
LOOP w W:28 S:3 P:2
LOOP o W:28 S:3 P:2
LOOP r W:28 S:3 P:2
LOOP d W:28 S:3 P:2
LOOP s W:28 S:3 P:2
LOOP , W:28 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:28 S:3 P:2
LOOP a W:28 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP n W:29 S:3 P:2
LOOP d W:29 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:29 S:3 P:2
LOOP c W:29 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP l W:30 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:30 S:3 P:2
LOOP a W:30 S:3 P:2
LOOP n W:30 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:30 S:3 P:2
LOOP s W:30 S:3 P:2 spc
 COPY {20}
LOOP t W:31 S:3 P:2
LOOP y W:31 S:3 P:2
LOOP l W:31 S:3 P:2
LOOP e W:31 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP   W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP . W:31 S:3 P:2 spc
LOOP {0A} W:31 S:3 P:2 spc dot
inp: 'the LANGUAGE  "C" is a procedural              programming language     .It was initially developed by "Dennis Ritchie"..            the Main feAtures of "C" language include low-level access to memory, simple set of keywords, and clean style                .{0A}'
buf: 'The language "C" is a procedural programming language. It was initially developed by "Dennis Ritchie"{0A} The main features of "C" language include low-level access to memory, simple set of keywords, and clean style.{0A}'
TOTAL: length=214 sentences=3 paragraphs=2 words=31
```

Comment: Great, thank you!
I've taken what you've done and implemented it on my code, basically, the professor restricted us to us only stdio.h and string.h libraries so I couldn't use any other functions...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution.

Hopefully this will show that you don't need all of the repetition.

I've only tested it with the example given, there might well still be edge cases where it might break.  You might want to allocate the `buffer` rather than using a specific value, but you might need to check to see if there are inputs that might lead to expansion.

Regarding capitals in the right places, there is no scope in the original for anything other than a single line, so no concept of paragraphs.  Therefore I've gone for caps at the start of sentences.

**NB:** OP didn't specify what the correct output was, given that the post is titled "wrong character count" so this is a best guess based on the requirements and some insight from the OP's code (which might as stated wasn't producing the right result).

I don't think that the point here is to fix the OP's bugs, but to illustrate alterantive ways of getting closer too, or achieving, a solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char original[] = "the LANGUAGE  \"C\" is a procedural              programming language     .It was initially developed by \"Dennis Ritchie\"..            the Main feAtures of \"C\" language include low-level access to memory, simple set of keywords, and clean style                .";

int main() {
    
    char buffer[256];
    strcpy(buffer, original);
    char *src, *dest;
    
    bool quoted = false;
    bool sentence = false;
    int periods = 0;
    bool space = false;
    bool paragraph = true;
    bool comma = false;
    int letters = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int sentences = 0;
    int paragraphs = 0;
    
    src = dest = buffer;

    for ( ; *src ; src++) {
        
        if (quoted) {

            switch (*src) {
                
            case '"': 
                quoted = false;
                break;
                
            }
        
            if ((*src >= 'a' && *src <= 'z') || (*src >= 'a' && *src <= 'z')) {
                letters++;
            } else {
                if (letters) {
                    words++;
                    letters = 0;
                }
            }
            
            *dest++ = *src;

        } else {
            
            switch (*src) {
                
            case '"':
                quoted = true;
                break;
                
            case ',':
                comma = true;
                continue;

            case ' ':
                if (letters) {
                    words++;
                    letters = 0;
                }
                space = true;
                continue;

            case '.':
                if (++periods == 2) {
                    *dest++ = '.';
                    *dest++ = '\n';
                    periods = 0;
                    paragraph = true;
                } else {
                    sentence = true;
                }
                continue;
            }
            
            if (comma) {
                *dest++ = ',';
                *dest++ = ' ';
                comma = space = false;
            }
            
            if (periods) {
                *dest++ = '.';
                periods = 0;
            }

            if (space) {
                if (!paragraph) {
                    *dest++ = ' ';
                }
                space = false;
            }
            
            if ((*src >= 'a' && *src <= 'z') || (*src >= 'a' && *src <= 'z')) {
                letters++;
            } else {
                if (letters) {
                    words++;
                    letters = 0;
                }
            }
            
            *dest++ = sentence || paragraph ? toupper(*src) : tolower(*src);

            if (sentence || paragraph) {
                if (letters) {
                    words++;
                }
                letters = 0;
            }
            
            if (sentence) {
                sentences++;
            }
            
            if (paragraph) {
                paragraphs++;
            }
            
            sentence = paragraph = false;
        }

    }
    
    if (sentence) {
        sentences++;
    }
    
    if (paragraph) {
        paragraphs++;
    }
    
    if (periods) {
        *dest++ = '.';
    }

    *dest++ = '\n';

    *dest = '\0';

    printf("\nInput Chars=%d\n\n\"%s\"\n", (int)strlen(original), original);
    printf("\nOutput Chars=%d, Words=%d, Sentences=%d, Paragraphs=%d\n\n\"%s\"\n", (int)strlen(buffer), words, sentences, paragraphs, buffer);
        
    return 0;
}
```

This produces:

```
Input Chars=259

"the LANGUAGE  "C" is a procedural              programming language     .It was initially developed by "Dennis Ritchie"..            the Main feAtures of "C" language include low-level access to memory, simple set of keywords, and clean style                ."

Output Chars=214, Words=34, Sentences=3, Paragraphs=2

"The language "C" is a procedural programming language. It was initially developed by "Dennis Ritchie".
The main features of "C" language include low-level access to memory, simple set of keywords, and clean style.
"
```

Comment: Pretty close. But, (1) needs that a double-dot (e.g. `..`) has to be converted to newline. From OP's code, we have to count chars, words, and paragraphs (see my answer for my take on what a "paragraph" is). I'd print the final string to ensure it's got capitalization and spacing correct.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks, I was avoiding trying to infer requirements from the code given that it was stated to be producing the wrong result.  I've updated to correct the obvious omissions (albeit slightly different from yours), but I think without further clarity from the OP I think we are speculating about what the result is meant to be.